# How to get product name from pivot table using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get product name from pivot table but unfortunately  i have no idea how can i get product name from pivot table please help me thanks.

**Product Model**

```
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductCategory', 'product_category', 'product_id', 'mf_product_category_id');
    }
```

**productcategory model**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_category', 'mf_product_category_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

**controller**

```
public function getproduct(Request $request)
    {
        // getting category Id
        $categoryId = $request->category;
        // getting product Id
        $name = trim($request->product);

        $productId = Product::where('name', $name)->pluck('id');

        $getProductcategory = ProductCategoryCount::whereIn('mf_product_category_id', $categoryId)->whereIn('product_id', $productId)->get();

        return $getProductcategory;
        // return response()->json($getproduct);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns), you can retrieve pivot table extra data using `withPivot` on the relationship.

Define `category` in the **Product Model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductCategory', 'product_category', 'product_id', 'mf_product_category_id')
        ->withPivot('Your_extra_data_on_pivot_table');
}
```

And by querying products, you can get category (which I suggest to be *categories*). You can retrieve it like this `$products->first()->pivot->{name of_your_extra_data_on_pivot_table}`

It is more optimized if you [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) this relationship.